Quotient group simplification exercise
I am doing some abstract algebra and it's been a hot second since I've done group theory. For both exercises, like $a, b, c, d$ all be free variables that generate a group with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients. I want to know what these groups can be simplified as over $\mathbb{Z}$ and am wondering if my computation is right/can be improved?

$\langle a,b, c+d \rangle / \langle a-b-c-d, -a+b-c-d \rangle  = \langle a,b, a-b \rangle / \langle -a+b-a+b \rangle= \langle a,b, b-a \rangle / \langle 2a -2b \rangle = \mathbb{Z}.$

$\langle b-c, a-d \rangle / \langle b-a-2c, -b+a-2d\rangle = \langle a+c, b+d \rangle = \langle \frac{a+b}{2} , \frac{a+b}{2} \rangle =\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. So What is the torsion part of this quotient?


Following Anne's response, I get that 2:
$$\langle b-c, a-d \rangle / \langle b-a-2c, -b+a-2d\rangle$$
$$ = \mathbb{Z}(b-c)\oplus \mathbb{Z}(a-d) / \mathbb{Z}(b-a -2c)\oplus \mathbb{Z}(-b+a-2d)$$
$$=\mathbb{Z}e \oplus \mathbb{Z}f/\mathbb{Z}(e-a-c)\oplus \mathbb{Z}(f-b-d)$$
$$=\mathbb{Z}(a+c)\oplus \mathbb{Z}(b+d)=\mathbb{Z}^2.$$


$$[\Bbb Za\oplus\Bbb Zb\oplus\Bbb Z(c+d)]/[\Bbb Z(a-b-c-d)\oplus\Bbb Z(-a+b-c-d)]$$$$= [\Bbb Za\oplus\Bbb Zb\oplus\Bbb Ze]/[\Bbb Z(a-b-e)+\Bbb Z(-a+b-e)]$$$$=[\Bbb Za\oplus\Bbb Zb]/[\Bbb Z(a-b-(-a+b))]$$$$=[\Bbb Za\oplus\Bbb Zf]/[\Bbb Z(2f)]$$$$=
\Bbb Z\oplus(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z).$$ The method and the result for 2 are the same.


Hi @AnneBauval, is it right that the second to last equality is more of an isomorphism because you are replacing b with a-b = f?

It is an equality.  $\Bbb Za\oplus\Bbb Zb=\Bbb Za\oplus\Bbb Z(a-b)$. ${a,b}$ and ${a,a-b}$ are both basis of the free $\Bbb Z$-module (=free abelian group) $\Bbb Za\oplus\Bbb Zb$.
